# Help with parsing lxml

Tags: python, lxml

To implement a college project, I need to handle XML files. For this I choose lxml after doing some research. However I can't seem to find some nice tutorial to help me get started. I can't choose most specifically which type of parsing I need to use. My XML files don't have that much data but speed is main concern, not memory.

Can anyone point me to some tutorial that would help me or some book that I can lookup? I have already tried the tutorial on lxml site but that didn't help me much. Is there some small application I can look up to get a hang of parsing XML with lxml

Comment: ... Is there anything in *particular* that you're having trouble with?

Comment: It might help to starte the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I don't know where to start and most specifically which type of parsing to use for my project.

TBH, I have never done a proper project before and that is the reason maybe for faltering.

Comment: Please don't consider this as homework. I am ready to do the hard work, I just need pointers on how to get started.

Comment: First what is the requirement of the project ie what does it do. Explain to yourself in non computing terms what you ned to do with the xml

Comment: @Mark: I need to read XML data from a file and issue shell commands from it.

Answer (score 3):

No applications but examples:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/
- http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pylxml/pylxml.pdf